# Laravel form in subview blade fails to POST upload

Tags: php, laravel, post, view, routes

I'm new to laravel and cant find a solution for this issue. I have a file chooser modal in a Laravel view called create.blade.php for uploading files. This subview is used in a blade called edit.blade.php for an edit page. My form returns a success message, but after doing some logging I can see that its not hitting the AttachmentController@Store with the POST request. When attempting to modify the route I get errors that "the POST method is not supported for this route.".

**Routes - routes/web.php**

```
//templates
    Route::get('/company/{company_id}/templates/{template_id}/{rev_id}', 'CompanyController@template_edit');
//attachments
    Route::get('/company/{company_id}/templates/{template_id}/attachment','AttachmentController@create');
    Route::post('/company/{company_id}/templates/{template_id}/attachment','AttachmentController@store');
```

**Controller - app/Http/Controllers/AttachmentController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use File; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Attachment;

class AttachmentController extends Controller
{
//begin store
    public function store(Request $request,$company_id,$template_id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'filenames' => 'required|max:100000'
        ]);
        if($request->hasfile('filenames'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('filenames') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().'.'.$file->extension();
                Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs('attachment', $file, $name);
                $originalname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = storage_path('app/attachment/'.$name);  
    //begin record
                $attachment = new Attachment();

                $attachment->name = $name;
                $attachment->originalname = $originalname;
                $attachment->filepath = $path;
                $attachment->company_id = $company->id;
                $attachment->template_id = $template->id;
                $attachment->rev_id = $rev->id;

                $attachment->save();
    //end record
            }
         }
        return back()->with('success', 'Your files have been successfully added.');
    }
//end store
//begin create
    public function create()
    {
        return view('company.templates.attachment.create');
    }
//end create
}
```

**View - resources/views/company/templates/edit.blade.php**

```
<!-- Begin Attachment Error / Success Pane -->
                  @if (count($errors) > 0)
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Sorry!</strong> There were problems with your input.<br><br>
                    <ul>
                      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                      @endforeach
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  @endif
                  @if(session('success'))
                  <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session('success') }}
                  </div>
                  @endif
<!-- End Attachment Error / Success Pane -->

<!-- Begin Attachment Modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right ml-2 mr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal">
                    Add Attachment
                    </button>
                      @include('company.templates.attachment.create')
<!-- End Attachment Modal -->

<!-- Begin Attachment Modal Script -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){
    $('#uploadModal').on('shown.bs.modal')      
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-submit").click(function(){ 
        var lsthmtl = $(".clone").html();
    });
    $("body").on("click",".btn-success-add",function(){ 
        var lsthmtl = $(".clone").html();
        $(".increment").after(lsthmtl);
    });
    $("body").on("click",".btn-danger",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".hdtuto").remove();
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- End Attachment Modal Script -->
```

**Subview - resources/views/company/templates/attachment/create.blade.php**

```
<form action="attachment/create.blade.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="modal fade" id="uploadModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uploadModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="uploadModalLongTitle">Upload Attachment</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container lst">
            {{csrf_field()}}

            <div class="input-group hdtuto control-group lst increment" >
              <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
              <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-success-add" type="button"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clone hide">
              <div class="hdtuto control-group lst input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
                <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
                <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I can tell the store action is not getting used because I have nothing within my storage folder or the database table after a "successful" upload. Seems to be route related.

Answer (score 0):

You have a form action of:

`action="attachment/create.blade.php"`

Your actual endpoint based on your route file is:

`/company/{company_id}/templates/{template_id}/attachment`.

Your form action needs to be pointing to the above URI, with the proper route parameters of `company_id` and `template_id`.

Your code is trying to post to `attachment/create.blade.php` which isn't correct...

Long story short, you'll need to swap out `attachment/create.blade.php` with a proper form action endpoint that matches your routes.

I can't see the rest of the code so it's hard to give much more advice on how to generate the action URI but what you'd be looking for is something like:

```
<form action="{{ action('AttachmentController@store', ['company_id' => $companyId, 'template_id' => $templateId]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Of course this is assuming both `$companyId` and `$templateId` are available.

Comment: Thanks for assisting. I had originally been using something similar like that for my form action but ended up hardcoding the file path in an attempt to force hitting the endpoint. I tried your suggestion but my controller wasn't passing the IDs properly, but with that in mind tried something like:

<form action="{{url('company')}}/{{ request()->route('company_id') }}/templates/{{ request()->route('template_id') }}/attachment" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

This worked. Looks like I need to fix those controller parameters for the proper way to work. Thank you.